# c# add more cases to a switch at runtime

Tags: c#, switch-statement, runtime, addition

I have made a program that is a test with multiple-choice questions. I'd like to make a new section where the "teacher" can add more questions to the test. The multiple choice is implemented with switch cases.

```
switch (qstNumber)
        {

            case 1: 
                txtQuestion.Text = "sdfgsdf"; // question



                rdoAnswer1.Text = "A";         // possible answers
                rdoAnswer2.Text = "B";
                rdoAnswer3.Text = "Γ ";
                rdoAnswer4.Text = "Δ";
                break;
```

So I was thinking to add a new textbox and to copy the text into a new switch. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add a switch at runtime; you don't want to use a switch at all.  You want to define a class where objects of the class are questions in the test.  Then you will have a List of objects of this class which is the test; you can add or remove items in this list at runtime.